# Cannot type some letter types in Tamil keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I am using Tamil language keyboard layout in input settings. When I try to use **Mei yelluthukal** (in Tamil) letters, I cannot enter them. They appear in a different form.

[image: gedit showing வ with a separated dotted circle with புள்ளி above, as if the base letter hasn't been entered]

The characters in the circle are what I am getting. What I want has been added (using gimp).

Any one who knows about the Tamil input settings methods for giving **Mei yelluthukal**, please tell me how to fix this.

I am using keyboard layout for input settings and layout is Tamil...

[image: uninformative keyboard layout dialog showing English US and Tamil]

Is there any way to send this to Ubuntu keyboard layout developers?

Comment: Please provide more information by editing the question. Have you enabled Tamil keyboard via **Language Support** or via **Keyboard Layout**? If using Language Suppor, are you using **ibus** or something else? If using Keyboard Layout, which of the 7 Tamil layouts are you using? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48088/how-do-i-input-text-in-tamil

Comment: Tamil26.wordpress.com visit the given website you will get your solution to type write in tamil and use any one of a tamil unicode font

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the link
"http://mmauran.net/blog/?p=102"
also you can try
"http://tamil99.org/"