# Tamil phonetic typing in Edubuntu 14.04

Tags: language-support, input-method

I'm trying to set up **Tamil phonetic** in Edubuntu 14.04. I cannot get Tamil phonetic in the text entry list.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is a [previous question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48088), but it refers to an old Ubuntu version where Text Entry was not invented.

Comment: @karel: Same objection - it talks about "IBus Preferences", which is irrelevant in 14.04.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The top voted answer is the same as yours except for it installs extra packages which I'm not sure are necessary. If you think your answer is better than that answer, which makes sense to me because it's more up to date, why not post it there where it would be seen by more people and maybe upvoted more if you explained  that it is more up to date?

Comment: @karel: It's not the installation of a few other (probably redundant) packages which differs. The main difference, which might well confuse users, is that the answer tells the user to open "IBus Preferences" instead of "Text Entry". That simply does not work in 14.04. But I followed your advice and posted my answer there as well. Not saying it's better, but it's certainly more up to date.

Comment: Hopefully it will do some good there, although without any explanation about iBus Preferences users will continue to stumble across the old answer or figure out by themselves how to do it in 14.04, or maybe give up entirely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24169/discussion-between-karel-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).

Answer (score 0):

- Install the ibus-m17n package:

  sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
- Log out and log in again.
- Select the **Tamil (phonetic (m17n)) (IBus)** option in Text Entry.

Comment: Im using the above mentioning method, but i still can't fine Tamil phonetic keyboard..

Comment: @HyoTitian: Is IBus the selected keyboard input method system in Language Support?