# Does Ubuntu have any input tools for typing in Indian languages?

Tags: input-language, input-method, tools

In Windows we have ***Microsoft Indic Tool*** and ***Google Input Tool*** for typing. In Ubuntu we can use Google input tool in browsers only. Does Ubuntu have any ***Ubuntu Indic*** or ***Input Tool*** for typing?

If yes, how can I install it?

**Notes**
I know Linux has many input methods and keyboard layout for various ways of typing.

Here I am asking about the names of software which is helpful for typing and prompts the user with appropriate or dictionary words.

> What's wrong with general keyboard?

Answer: There's nothing wrong with it but Input Tools are awesome and very helpful.

Here are some links for clarification:

- [Google IME | wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_IME)
- [Microsoft Indic Language Tool | wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Indic_Language_Input_Tool)

I've already read the following posts:

- [How do I input text in Tamil?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48088/how-do-i-input-text-in-tamil)
- [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages)
- [Ubuntu help wiki page on ibus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ibus)

Comment: Could you explain what it needs to do?

Comment: @Tim Name of any Input Tool for easier typing. Like Google Input Tool. Fully based on Ubuntu or Linux.

Comment: What is wrong with the keyboard?

Comment: Typing tool which prompt words like Google Input Tool during typing.

Comment: So an autocomplete?

Comment: @Tim I know in Linux so many keyboard layout. Ex. Devanagari in-script, bolnagari, phonetics etc. But they not have features like Input Tool. Input Tools are awesome for many reasons.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what features you want.

Comment: @Tim ok I edit my question and explain in brief. just now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24537/discussion-between-madhav-nikam-and-tim).

Comment: Sounds like what you want is an implementation of Google IMA as an ibus plugin, or one similar to it, which works well for Indian languages?

Comment: Maybe http://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-typing-booster/documentation.html can be useful?  (I don't think it has packages for Ubuntu currently though, so you would have to build it yourself.)

Comment: To type Bangla, we have a nice keyboard called [Avro][1]. You can install in from [here][2]. The web interface is [here][3]. You type something there any see how it works. 


  [1]: http://linux.omicronlab.com/
  [2]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/764706/how-to-install-ibus-avro-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts
  [3]: http://avro.im

Comment: Avro seems preety nice, but it does not seem to support  transliteration to HINDI.  I will contact the developer Sarin, whether he would be able to provide support for Hindi. This tool is system wide not just libre office specific.

Answer (score 1):

The tool that worked well for me is [GXLiterate- A Google Transliteration Service based transliterator for OpenOffice.org for Indic Languages](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/gxliterate-google-transliteration-service-based-transliterator-openofficeorg-indic-languages).

It's a libre office extension, but serves the purpose.

Cons: it does not provide an option to choose between transliteration suggestions, it directly translates to the language selected,  sometimes with wrong translation but, most of the time, accurate transliteration.

I am enjoying the same in LibreOffice writer. It solved my problem, however it would be better if there were some shortcut to disable and enable the same.

I also tried [XlitHindi](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/xlithindi), which was developed by CADD, but unfortunately it didn't work on LibreOffice 5; it opened but LibreOffice froze, so I uninstalled the extension and started using Gxliterate, which is working pretty well for me.

<sub>Editor's Note: This answer is [Kanhiya's](https://askubuntu.com/users/175850/kanhiya).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I am using `CentOS` with `xfce` now, but I think `Ubuntu` has the same package and properties.</sub>

---

1. First add Indian keyboard layout to your keyboard properties and ensure that appropriate fonts are installed.
2. Install package [florence](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html):

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install florence
   ```
3. Run this command so you can choose your keyboard layout (both virtual and real):

   ```
   $ florence
   ```

---

Keyboard screenshot:

[image: keyboard screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To have autocomplete support in LibreOffice, you have to install the dictionary extension for your native language, for instance here is the [Tamil Dictionary extension project for Libreoffice](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/tamil-spellchecker) and [OpenOffice extensions](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/search?f%5B0%5D=field_project_tags%3A157) are also compatible if you have any of that kind for your localization support and after setting up your native dictionary, just hit <kbd>space</kbd> while typing to auto-correct if it says the word spelling is wrong . And there are also dictionaries as [web browser addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/) to have language support for web, specially for Mozilla Firefox.

There is an [m17n-project](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/m17n)  which helps in adding support for new input methods if not available in the mainstream. You can look for your native language support on [ibus-m17n](https://www.nongnu.org/m17n/manual-en/m17nDBData.html) and if the method you want is available there, then you just have to install `ibus-m17n` package by running this command:

```
sudo apt install ibus-m17n
```

and then choosing your preferred ibus input method after starting the `ibus-engine`. Choose what suits you.

Comment: A little confused about whether if you are looking for virtual keyboard like onboard which maps your keyboard virtually for whatever the active layout is so you can type with your mouse or touch and also has a [typing assistant](https://imgur.com/JOb9h1E) though it works only in English (the word suggestion).

Comment: I didn't find any release of the [Tamil dictionary extension yet](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/tamil-spellchecker) :( I guess they are working on it...