# How to get sidebars, terminals etc. again which are disappeared after executing sudo apt-get remove ibus-avro-trusty command?

Tags: 16.04, ibus

I wanted to use phonetic Bangla in Ubuntu. I got [this](http://linux.omicronlab.com/ubuntu_14.04.html) instruction manual, but it did not work. I thought as it is for 14.04, I should find another way.

So, I searched and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764706/how-to-install-ibus-avro-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) post. When I tried to execute the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i avro_2.0-1_all.deb
```

it showed some overwriting conflict with `ibus-avro-trusty`.

Then I decided to uninstall the previous one by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus-avro-trusty
```

While executing the above command, I noticed that some icons started disappearing including `Ubuntu Software Center`. I thought a restart would fix them.

But Alas! When I restarted, Both the side bar and up-bar disappeared! Even Terminal is not opening while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

I could copy all my files safely from a folder in desktop.

Is there anyway to fix it? Or should I reinstall ubuntu?

Note that, my version of ubuntu is 16.04.1.