# Installing Avro in 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, ibus, ibus-avro

How can I install Avro in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release? I have tried with [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764706/how-to-install-ibus-avro-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) but not working (previously worked in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Edit: This question is not a duplicated version of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764706/how-to-install-ibus-avro-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts). Seems like installing Avro in 18.04 LTS needs some additional steps.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest [Avro release on GitHub](https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases)?  What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: The top answer of the linked question recommends nearly the same steps as the accepted answer to this one.

Comment: Avro was working perfectly on 16.04 LTS. I could write in Bangla on any window on internet. Upgraded to 18.04 LTS and successfully installed ' avro_2.1-3_all.deb'. Bangla not showing. Tried all recipes mentioned here with no avail. Now I installed a new hdd. Installed 18.04.2 LTS. Did everything like before. Set 'Complex text layout' to 'Bengali (Bangladesh)' in Libre Office. Still no Bangla writing on. Please help me.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136041/ibus-qt4-package-missing-from-disco-packages
here is the link that will work for complete installation of avro.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am using Avro in 18.04 LTS and it's working.

Here is the steps you need to follow.

1. Go to **Language Support**. Click **install/remove languages**.

   [image: Language support dialog]
2. Select **Bangla** from the list and click <kbd>apply</kbd>. After installing Bangla language support you should start installing Avro.

   [image: Installed Languages dialog]
3. The resulting window should look like this:

   [image: Language Support dialog with Bangla]
4. Download and install avro from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases). I use 2.0 version

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i avro_2.0-1_all.deb
   ```
5. You will see some missing packages. To install those, run the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
6. Restart `ibus`

   ```
   ibus restart
   ```
7. Now go to **Settings > Region and language > Add an input source > Bangla > Bengali (Avro Phonetic)**

   [image: Add an input source dialog]
8. Enjoy typing Bangla in Avro keyboard.

Comment: Installed successfully. Not working on 18,04 LTS. I had no problem on 16.04 LTS. Please help.

Comment: @bluepearlsky What exactly is your problem? Avro is not showing up in the list or everything is fine but Bangla is not appearing while typing?

Comment: First I tried the above tutorial.Got this display.

ashoke@ashoke-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg -i avro_2.0-1_all.deb

[sudo] password for ashoke:

dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process ashoke@ashoke-desktop:~$

    Then installed 'Avro 2.1-3' from Ubuntu Software.

    Avro Installed enter image description here

    Default Avro preferences. enter image description here

    Bangla script not showing. enter image description here

Therefore,the problem. Bangla is not appearing while typing. :-)

Comment: Though, I am not an expert but during installation, I have used latest Debian package from GitHub. This method worked for me without any additional step.

Comment: Avro not installaed. https://ibb.co/gA91tJ

Comment: https://ibb.co/gAFXYJ

Comment: I got the avro after clicking the Bangla(Bangladesh). Thank you.

Comment: You can also find avro in Ubuntu Store

Comment: @mahir Are you sure?

Comment: It worked for me

Comment: the following error occurs 'dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'avro_2.0-1_all.deb': No such file or directory'

Answer (score 9):

You may have run into [a bug](https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/issues/130), which now has been fixed.

Avro Phonetic has recently been made available to Ubuntu users via an official package, which includes that bugfix.

To install it:

```
sudo apt install ibus-avro
```

After that add input source by following steps:

- Log out and log in again
- **Settings > Region and language > Add an input source > Bangla** (or Other) **> Bangla (Avro Phonetic)**

Answer (score 1):

I've installed successfully and found the settings for input source at the top bar.

[image: the embedded image]