# Avro is installed, but bangla writting is still not coming

Tags: 18.04, ibus-avro

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. To install Avro I first downloaded the latest version(avro_2.1-3_all.deb) from github using command

```
$ wget "https://github.com/ugcoder/avro/releases/download/v2.1/avro_2.1-3_all.deb"
```

Then installed:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i avro_2.1-3_all.deb
```

Then finally ran these command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -fy
$ ibus restart
```

Before these download and installation, I entered "Language Support" and ensured that the box for Bangla is ticked in "Installed language". Also ensured that Keyboard input method id IBus.

Now once avro is installed, I went to settings and added Bengali(Avro Phonetic)" as input source.

Now I opened LibreOffice Writer switched to Avro using `super+space`. Everything was set, only all that is coming are English letters. Same happened on `gedit`, same happening now: I wrote this whole question with Avro selected!

What's happening?

To enquire, I checked to keyboard layout of Avro Phonetic. Surprisingly avro's keyboard layout is identical to English(US)! I then manually downloaded the avro fonts and copied them to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` and restarted my PC. The result is same. Now what can I do to write Bangla with Avro?

Comment: I followed this link to to install avro:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035875/installing-avro-in-18-04-lts

Comment: Update: I've removed Avro 2.1-3 using `"$ sudo apt-get purge avro"` then reinstalled Avro 2.0-1 following the installation procedure given in avro github page. The result is same, I still can't write Bangla with Avro!

Comment: Is ibus showing up in the notification menu? Does the icon change to avro icon when you press `super+space`?  Are you sure that the shortcut for toggling is super+ space? Check ibus settings

Comment: Archisman Panigrahi: Yes, Avro appears in notification menu when I press super+space. I used avro before in this PC. For a reason I had to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04. It worked perfectly in the previous installation. Dunno why now its causing problem.

Comment: Have you selected the Keyboard input method system to "ibus"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Avro Keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280905/how-to-install-avro-keyboard-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 2):

try this command and then restart ibus. Restart your PC if needed.

```
rm ~/.candidate-selections.json
ibus restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same thing. In my case, I uninstalled Bangla from Language input source. Unistalled Avro too. Then Reinstalled Avro from [here](https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases). Then do the things stated below.

Just click on Bangla(Bangladesh) [image: Like this Image] and a new window will come.

Select Avro Phonetic from there.
[image: Like this one]
I think it will fix the thing!

Answer (score 1):

You may have run into [a bug](https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/issues/130), which now has been fixed.

Avro Phonetic has recently been made available to Ubuntu users via an official package, which includes that bugfix.

To install it:

```
sudo apt install ibus-avro
```