# How to install Avro Keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, ibus-avro

How to install Avro Keyboard since developer's instruction doesn't work smoothly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Avro Keyboard - Ubuntu: 22.04

### Installation:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start terminal and run following command

```
sudo apt install ibus-avro
```

**Restart system or Log out - Log in**

Go to `Settings` > `Keyboard` (`Settings` > `Region & Language` in 20.04)

In `Input Sources` click `+`

Click `Bangla` or `Bangla (Bangladesh)`

Finally select `Bangla (Avro Phonetic)`

Now it should work just fine.
If not make sure your `Keyboard Input Method System` is > `IBus`

**Common Problem**

Avro Stops writing Bangla. Try to restart ibus.

```
ibus restart
```

Answer (score 9):

### How to install Avro Phonetic in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

- Open `Ubuntu Software`
- Search `Avro Phonetic` in `Ubuntu Software` search bar
  [image: avro phonetic in ubuntu software]
- Click `install`
  [image: install Avro Phonetic]
- Restart the machine or Logout and then login again
- Open `Settings` > `Region & Language`
- Click on the `+` (plus) icon in `Input Sources`
- Search for `Bangla` and then click on `Bangla (Avro Phonetic)`
  [image: Add Bangla Avro Phonetic]
- The `Avro Phonetic` will be added to the `Input Sources`
  [image: Avro phonetic in Input Sources]
- Now you will get a dropdown for selecting `bn` for Bangla language in top bar right corner
- You can switch between different `Input Source` using `win` + `space` keyboard shortcut
  [image: Write using Bangla]

### Reference

- [Install Avro Phonetic in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://arshovon.com/blog/install-avro-ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: ধন্যবাদ। এটা কাজ করেছে।

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 22.04**
If `Settings` > `Keyboard`/`Region` does not work then try following

- Remember to log out or reboot after installation of `Avro` and   then proceed to the next step.
- `Ibus preference` from the system menu or `ibus-setup` from the
  terminal.
- Click on the `Add` button in `Input Method`
- Search for `Bangla` and then click on `Avro Phonetic`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes avro stops writing Bangla. It starts writing in English after a couple of words.
I have switched off the preferences option altogether and got rid of this problem.

Using Ubuntu budgie 20.04 (Dual boot with windows)