# How to install Avro keyboard in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I tried to install the Avro keyboard according to this link [install avro in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280905/how-to-install-avro-keyboard-in-ubuntu-20-04). But this is not working in KDE PLASMA. How can I do that? Is there any different approach for KDE Plasma?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: This is not Ubuntu. It is Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

First install ibus-avro

`sudo apt install ibus-avro`

Then go to Application launcher. Search IBus preferences. Go to Input Method. Click on Add. Click on three dots on the dialogue. Search Bangla. Then click on Avro Phonetic. Click on Add.

You are done!