# How to install Avro and writing Bangla in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I have installed ibus-avro in my ubuntu 22.04 but I can't configure the language switching.  Does ubuntu 22.04 support bangla writing?

Comment: You may find my reply in this thread.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1446423/393159

Answer (score 0):

In my case using <kbd>Win/Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> switched typing.