# how to install avro keyboard in ubuntu 23.10

Tags: software-installation

I am new in ubuntu . I install ubuntu 23.10 . Now, I can't install avro keyboard in my ubuntu 23.10 . please help me .

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to install Avro Keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280905/how-to-install-avro-keyboard-in-ubuntu-20-04)