# IBus Avro is not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ibus-avro

I've installed Avro in my ubuntu 18.04. Then it works fine. But recently it is not working. Like by pressing **Super + space**, I can change the language but although I select Bangla it appears English alphabets.

I've checked all settings in **Language support** and it seems that there is no change happens.

How can I again make it workable?

This question may seem duplicate to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035875/installing-avro-in-18-04-lts) but, in this case, the Avro installation is absolutely fine and it was working for a time then suddenly it stopped working. That time although i on the IBus Avro the Bangla fonts was not coming.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035875/installing-avro-in-18-04-lts?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Avro in 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035875/installing-avro-in-18-04-lts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have run into [a bug](https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/issues/130), which now has been fixed.

Avro Phonetic has recently been made available to Ubuntu users via an official package, which includes that bugfix.

To install it:

```
sudo apt install ibus-avro
```