# "ibus-qt4" package missing from disco packages

Tags: package-management, 19.04, ibus-avro

I tried to install [avro](https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases). But it depends on **ibus-qt4**. When I [searched](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ibus-qt4&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=disco&section=all), it is not in Disco packages. How can I install the package?

Comment: https://github.com/maateen/avro/issues/123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install this software if you download required dependencies from 18.10 (cosmic) repository manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ibus-qt/libibus-qt1_1.3.3-1build2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libibus-qt1_1.3.3-1build2_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libicu60_60.2-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ibus-qt/ibus-qt4_1.3.3-1build2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./ibus-qt4_1.3.3-1build2_amd64.deb

wget https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases/download/v2.1/avro_2.1-3_all.deb
sudo apt install ./avro_2.1-3_all.deb
```

Note: manual package installation is not recommended, but in your particular case I do not see other possibilities.

Comment: Is it ok to install from another repository?

Comment: It is OK for your particular case. But is not recommended in usual way.

Comment: Some Ubuntu flavours (like Xubuntu) doesn't include IBus input method out of the box. One has to install `ibus, ibus-m17n, ibus-gtk, ibus-gtk3` packages before installing Avro. Avro is working on 19.04 using above method but it may not work in the future. Best option is to learn real Bangla typing which Ubuntu easily supports.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution would be installing Avro from Gunnar Hjalmarsson's PPA-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gunnarhj/avro
sudo apt install avro
```

This version isn't dependent on "ibus-qt4".

*Edit by Gunnar Hjalmarsson:*

Well, I have closed down that PPA. The reason is that Avro Phonetic has now been made available to Ubuntu users via an official package.

To install it:

```
sudo apt install ibus-avro
```

It does not have that `ibus-qt4` dependency. `ibus-avro` in the Ubuntu archive installs the latest upstream software, including a bugfix which is important to Ubuntu users.