# Can't install Avro for inputting Bangla on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, ibus-avro

I downloaded `avro_2.1-3_all.deb` from [this page](https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases), but when I tried to install it I found that it depends on the `ibus-qt4` package which is [not available in the Ubuntu 19.04 archive](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1757660).

How can I install Avro on Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ibus-qt4" package missing from disco packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136041/ibus-qt4-package-missing-from-disco-packages)

Comment: @HattinGokbori87: Possibly. But suggesting that people install packages from 18.10, as is done in the accepted answer, is not a nice solution. I saw that you mentioned my PPA in an own answer, but didn't mention that installing `avro_2.0-1_all.deb` is an option.

Comment: Edited that answer to clarify that installing from the PPA is comparatively better. I didn't mentioned version 2.0.1 as it contains some more bugs.

Comment: @HattinGokbori87: Ok, no big deal. It's true that `2.0-1` does not include the ibus dependencies, but that "Arabic" bug is history (only affected a couple of Ubuntu versions which are now EOL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avro Phonetic has now been made available to Ubuntu users via an official package.

To install it:

```
sudo apt install ibus-avro
```

It does not have that `ibus-qt4` dependency. `ibus-avro` in the Ubuntu archive installs the latest upstream software, including a bugfix which is important to Ubuntu users.