# Activating ibus-avro

Tags: package-management, 20.04, ibus, ibus-avro

I have installed ibus-avro using
`sudo apt install ibus-avro`

How do I activate it ? I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Apparently i need to change ibus preferences but i could not find the option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you ask [the manual](https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/blob/master/README.md#usage) :)

Comment: [That one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1035875/996009) is pretty explicit also ! :-)

Comment: @B.duGaray: The first one you mention does not apply to a GNOME desktop, and the second one is far too wordy and includes several unnecessary steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Avro Keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280905/how-to-install-avro-keyboard-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- After having installed the package, log out and log in again.
- Go to *Settings -> Region & Language*
- In the *Input Sources* section click the + button and add *Bangla (Avro Phonetic)* to your list of input sources (you find it in the "Other" section or, if you have generated a Bangla locale, by clicking a Bangla submenu)

After that you can switch to Avro Phonetic - either via the input source menu in the top bar or by using the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut - and start typing.

P.S. And no, since you are on Ubuntu, don't bother with IBus Preferences.

Comment: Thanks a lot  :) That was really helpful and easy to follow.