# Avro Bangla keyboard is installed but not showing up language selection list to select on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus, ibus-avro

I could successfully installed and used Avro in my previous Ubuntu 18.02.
This installation problem arises in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

To install Avro, I am following the instructions from this thread: http://libtechbwn.blogspot.com/2018/06/install-avro-phonetics-in-ubuntu-1804.html

I have followed each step as instructed. I think the main problem occurs of my installation is in **Manage Installed Languages**. In **Manage Installed Languages**, after adding Bangla language package, I am losing all Bangla language selection options in language choose list.

The below mentioned pictures visualize the result of Bangla language package installation and result of the installation:

[image: **Bangla Language Package** has been installed]

After installing the language, the language selection list look like this:
[image: Language selection list after Bangla language package installation]

I have restart **ibus** with `restart ibus` as instructed, it didn’t return any error.

I have tried to follow few threads here on Ask Ubuntu to solve my installation problem but in vain.

I have specially followed the following threads:

- [Installing Avro in 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035875/installing-avro-in-18-04-lts)
- [How to install ibus-avro in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764706/how-to-install-ibus-avro-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

I have also tried to install from Github, from this repository: 
https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases
where the instruction are locate here:
https://github.com/maateen/avro

Where could I possibly have done wrong during my Avro installation, so that this problem occurs?

***After successfully adding Avro phonetic I got following output from different environment:***

- System Info

[image]
 - Web Browser

[image]
 - Libre Office

[image]
 - Notepade++

[image]

- StickyNote

[image]

- Avro version

[image]

- Avro 2.0.1 and 2.1.3 behavior in Ubuntu Default Text Editor

[image]

- Avro 2.0.1 and 2.1.3 behavior in Bijiben Quickly jot notes Note 3.28.1-1

[image]

Comment: What if you scroll down a bit more and look for *Bengali (Avro Phonetic)*?

Comment: Nothing showing up. Even if I start typing Ben, then it's become empty window.

Comment: I have a new theory; please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed the Bangla language from "Manage Installed Languages", the Bangla/Bengali input source options were moved from the "Other" window. Actually I think that you now see a "Bangla" item at the very first window when clicking the + button, and if you select "Bangla", a sub window will open with a number of options, including "Bengali (Avro Phonetic)".

Comment: Now I am outside. I will be at home within a hour and I will check my installation and reply your answer.

Comment: I did not notice this. Before installing  *** Bangla lanuage package from Manage Installed Languages***, _Bangla_ would be displayed only in the **other** window. That's why after installing the package, I went the other tab to see if the Bengali (Avro Phonetic) has been added. After reading your answer, now I've checked and I  found that the Benglai(Avro Phonetic) and all other Bangla options are being displayed at top of the window.

Comment: @Mamun: Good. Assuming you are on a standard Ubuntu desktop with GNOME, are you successful in using it for typing Bangla? Asking because of what I wrote in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148147).

Comment: Yes, I could with some exception.

Well, I don't have good knowledge whether I have GNOME or Unity. I am seeing in System Info that I have GNOME. For clarification, I am adding the screenshots of my System Info window. 

I have successfully written in Bangla with Aubro phonetic in web browser, LibreOfiice. But it did not work in StickyNote or Notepade++. Please check my edited question to see the screenshots. I have added the screenshots of each output.

Comment: @Mamun: That's indeed GNOME. May I ask which version of avro you installed finally?

Comment: Sorry for delay reply, I had to go outside again and just now I'm  being able to answer your question. I don't know how to check Avro's version in Ubuntu. I have followed few tutorial to install Avro and never uninstall any previous installed one from previous tutorial. So there could more than one version.  Most probably I have installed **Avro_2.0_1_all.deb"** . If I would knew how to check Avro's installed version in Ubuntu then I could be specific.

Comment: @Mamun: I did some research, and by now I'm pretty sure that it's version `2.0-1` you have. One way to confirm it is to open a terminal window and enter `apt show avro`. Anyway, I figured out my own problem and edited the answer I linked to above. In short: Version `2.1-3` has issues and should be avoided.

Comment: Ok. Now I am going work. After reutrning home, I will check the version.

Comment: Well, it seems that I have `2.1-3` version.
I am attaching the terminal output produced by the command  from your comment to check Avro version,. Please check the screenshots to see in detail.

Comment: @Mamun: Now I'm confused. But considering that it works for you, you really don't need to care about my doubts about that version. That is, unless you want to try `2.0-1` to check if it makes a difference in those apps where it doesn't work currently.

Comment: Ok, I will try on weekends 2.0-1 version and let you know the result. Is there any easy way to shift from one version to another version of Avro? I tried to find some instructions to uninstall Avro, but did not find a good one.

Comment: @Mamun: Step 6 in the guide you linked to is fine. You don't need to uninstall the current version first; it will just be replaced with the new (i.e. older) version.

Comment: I have tired both Avro `2.0-1` and `2.1-3` and receiving results are being displayed in the above last two attached images. Both behave same except in **Ubuntu's default notes** and one sticky not editor I've downloaded from Ubuntu Software, **Bijiben Quickly jot notes**, version -3.28.1-1. In these, two newly text editors,  `2.0-1` could successfully write in Bangla where `2.1-3` could not. 
Please check the last two attached images to see the output. In both tests, the Avro version is written on right side of text.

Comment: @Mamun: Thanks, then our observations are similar. I usually use `gedit` (Ubuntu's default editor) to test when playing with IBus. The conclusion seems to be that `2.0-1`works more reliably than `2.1-3`.

Comment: I have forgot about `gedit`. Now I have tested Avro in `gedit`, both version work fine. 
Yes, it seems to me also that `2.0.-1` are more reliable than `2.1-3`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a second answer to this question, since Avro Phonetic now has been made available to Ubuntu users via an official package.

To install it:

```
sudo apt install ibus-avro
```

That package is better than both `2.0-1` and `2.1-3`. It installs the latest upstream software, including a bugfix which is important to Ubuntu users, and unlike `2.1-3` it does not depend on the `ibus-qt4` package, which is not present in the Ubuntu 19.04 archive.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I will try this version.

Comment: Today I had the opportunity to test  this new installation method. I installed in this way and it works fine.

Comment: Not working on my system