# How can I enable Sinhala,Tamil kit for Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, language-support, support

I can't type Sinhala or Tamil language in Ubuntu 15.10 except LKLUG. I want to type Sinhala language as well as English (UK).

Comment: posible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/48088/how-do-i-input-text-in-tamil

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings
Click on Language Support
 [image]

Click install/remove languages button

check the required languages

click Apply changes

give authentication for downloading and wait for installation

then goto system settings and Click on Text entry Settings

press "+" button 
add required languges from the list
[image: Click here to see images]

then click on the keyboard indicator and select language for typing